# What's the meaning of "NoWorkingDirectory" string value in Windows Registry?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, right-click, context-menu

Empty "NoWorkingDirectory" string value is often used in Windows Registry when user-defined Right-Click menu items are created. For example to be able to open PowerShell when right-clicking on folder backround in Windows Explorer (as opposed to right-clicking on folder itself, in that case "NoWorkingDirectory" is not used):

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\powershell]
@="Open PowerShell Here"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\powershell\command]
@="C:\\\\Windows\\\\System32\\\\WindowsPowerShell\\\\v1.0\\\\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%V'"
```

However, I am not clear on actual purpose of this value. It is always used empty in all samples I found. What exactly does it signify?

Comment: I would imagine if there was a directory value it would only work in that directory. Do you have other examples?

Comment: http://www.randyrants.com/2007/02/vista_tip_eleva.html

Comment: http://www.windows7home.net/add-administrator-privilege-to-right-button-in-windows-7/

Comment: My guess is that it's the folder used to execute from if there's no Working Folder provided when the shell command is called (similar to the "Start In:" option in a Shortcut's properties).  When empty it probably assumes the current folder.  But again, this is just guessing. ;)

Answer (score 12):

WorkingDirectory is a property of the System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo, when you Right Click, you are starting a new process and this setting allows you to start a process without the current directory becoming the "Working Directory".  It then defaults to the System32 for the command being run.

So you would use "NoWorkingDirectory" when you are not wanting the location right clicked to become part of the environmental path for the duration of the script.  Useless setting in 90% of cases, unless you have similar named files in multiple path locations which could get sticky unless "NoWorkingDirectory" is specified.

See more details here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: For instance, if I have a copy of DISM in a folder and right click on it, "NoWorkingDirectory" would allow me to access the copy in System32 over the one in the directory I right clicked on.  See, it's kinda useless because more often than not I want the copy in the folder I clicked on.

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer for Windows users without any programming skills

Running an executable with one (or more) directory/file name(s) passed as argument(s) to the executable via a shell context menu item opened by right clicking on a directory or file (on right side of a *Windows File Explorer* window) results in starting the executable with current working directory being set for this executable with

1. the directory containing the clicked directory/file on no registry value `NoWorkingDirectory` present
   or
2. the directory `C:\Windows\System32` or more precisely `%SystemRoot%\system32` with the registry value `NoWorkingDirectory` present in Windows registry.

Many not good coded executables and scripts require the first variant with current working directory being set to the directory containing the directory or file to process. That is the reason why the first variant is the default.

In some cases the first variant causes an unwanted behavior like on running `cmd.exe` to process a batch script which gets passed the clicked directory/file name as argument and the directory/file is referenced using its [UNC path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Universal_Naming_Convention).

The second variant with `NoWorkingDirectory` present in the Windows registry can be used for all really good coded executables and scripts.

---

### Long answer for Windows users and programmers interested in details

The Windows kernel library contains the function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) which is used by `explorer.exe` and most other executables capable running another executable without or with a [STARTUPINFO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure to start a Windows executable. One of the parameters of function `CreateProcess` is `lpCurrentDirectory` – a long pointer to the string with directory path to set as current working directory for the process to create. The pointer value can be also null to instruct `CreateProcess` to use the current directory of the process calling `CreateProcess` as current working directory for the process to create. Most executables call `CreateProcess` with a null pointer for the function parameter `lpCurrentDirectory`.

The *Windows File Explorer* (`explorer.exe`) calls `CreateProcess` with the directory path of the directory containing the directory/file on which the user clicked with secondary (usually right) pointing device (often mouse) button and clicked in opened context menu on the item resulting in starting an executable with the clicked directory/file name as argument.

The registry string value `NoWorkingDirectory` changes the behavior on how `explorer.exe` calls `CreateProcess` regarding to function parameter `lpCurrentDirectory`. The current directory is always the system directory of Windows with this registry string value present, i.e. the directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` which on most Windows machines expands to `C:\Windows\System32`.

That can be seen as follows:

Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) window and run the following harmless commands:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\NoWorkingDirectoryTest" /ve /d "No working directory test"
reg add "HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\NoWorkingDirectoryTest\command" /ve /d "cmd.exe /D /C C:\Temp\DirTest\DirTest.cmd \"%V"\""

md "C:\Temp\DirTest"
echo @echo Current directory is: ^"%^CD%^">"C:\Temp\DirTest\DirTest.cmd"
echo @echo Batch file started with: %0 %*>>"C:\Temp\DirTest\DirTest.cmd"
echo @echo Command line used is: %^CMDCMDLINE%>>"C:\Temp\DirTest\DirTest.cmd"
echo @pause>>"C:\Temp\DirTest\DirTest.cmd"
```

The two `reg` command lines add to Windows registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\NoWorkingDirectoryTest]
@="No working directory test"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\NoWorkingDirectoryTest\command]
@="cmd.exe /D /C \"C:\\Temp\\DirTest\\DirTest.cmd\" \"%V\""
```

The command `md` and the four `echo` command lines create the batch file `C:\Temp\DirTest\DirTest.cmd` with the following command lines:

```
@echo Batch file started with: %0 %*
@echo Current directory is: "%CD%"
@echo Command line used is: %CMDCMDLINE%
@pause
```

Now start *Windows File Explorer* on not already running and browse on left side in folder tree to the directory `C:\Windows\System32\drivers`. Click with the right mouse button **on right side** on the folder `etc` and left click in the opened context menu on the item **No working directory test** just added before to the Windows registry.

The just before created batch file is executed displaying in a console window:

```
Current directory is: "C:\Windows\System32\drivers"
Batch file started with: C:\Temp\DirTest\DirTest.cmd "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc"
Command line used is: "cmd.exe" /D /C C:\Temp\DirTest\DirTest.cmd "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc"
```

The first output line shows the current directory set by `CreateProcess` on starting `cmd.exe` with the four arguments according to the string passed with `lpCurrentDirectory` by the parent process `explorer.exe`. It can be seen that the *Windows File Explorer* called `CreateProcess` in this case with `C:\Windows\System32\drivers` as current working directory path.

The second output line shows with which arguments the batch file was started including argument 0 which is the string used to reference the batch file as added to Windows registry.

The third line outputs how `cmd.exe` itself was started by `explorer.exe` respectively `CreateProcess`. `cmd.exe` although stored in the registry without surrounding `"` is enclosed in `"` on being started by `explorer.exe`.

The registry string value `NoWorkingDirectory` does not exist at the moment. That is the reason why the current working directory for `cmd.exe` is set to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers` which is the current directory of `explorer.exe` on right clicking **on right side** on the folder `etc` with currently active folder in *Windows File Explorer* being `C:\Windows\System32\drivers`.

Now right click in *Windows File Explorer* **on left side** in folder tree on the directory `C:\Windows` while the currently active folder is still `C:\Windows\System32\drivers` and left click in context menu on the item **No working directory test**.

There is one more console window opened with displaying following lines:

```
Current directory is: "C:\WINDOWS\system32"
Batch file started with: C:\Temp\DirTest\DirTest.cmd "C:\Windows"
Command line used is: "cmd.exe" /D /C C:\Temp\DirTest\DirTest.cmd "C:\Windows"
```

The second and the third line are as expected. But the current directory is neither `C:\Windows\System32\drivers` nor `C:\` and also not `C:\Windows`. So it can be seen that starting an executable with the directory containing a directory does not always work as expected when the user right clicks in folder tree on left side on a directory or a virtual shell folder.

There can be also seen that the current working directory path is not even the real directory path of the Windows system directory as in this case would be displayed `C:\Windows\System32` and not `C:\WINDOWS\system32`. Please note the differences in case of some letters. The Windows system directory path really used here is a concatenation of the registry value `SystemRoot` under key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` which has the string value `C:\WINDOWS` concatenated with fixed string `\system32`. The real directory path is `C:\Windows\System32`.

A batch file or executable or any other script designed for being executed by `explorer.exe` or similar programs via a context menu item should always take into account that the current directory can be a completely different directory than the directory containing the passed directory/file name(s). The process calling `CreateProcess` defines which directory is the current directory for the created process.

`cmd.exe` has a special behavior on being started with current directory path being a UNC path. It changes the current directory in this case to `%SystemRoot%` (Windows directory) and outputs the information:

> \\ComputerName\SharedFolder\Resource
> CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
> UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.

That is done by `cmd.exe` for downwards compatibility because of many executables are not running correct on current directory path not starting with a drive letter and a colon.

It is possible to run in a command prompt window:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v DisableUNCCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

That disables the Universal Naming Convention (UNC) check for command sessions and `cmd.exe` accepts also a current directory with a UNC path.

Okay, back to registry value `NoWorkingDirectory`. Execute in a command prompt window now:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\NoWorkingDirectoryTest" /v NoWorkingDirectory /t REG_SZ
```

There is added the registry string value `NoWorkingDirectory` with no value. So the registry contains now:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\NoWorkingDirectoryTest]
@="No working directory test"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\NoWorkingDirectoryTest\command]
@="cmd.exe /D /C C:\\Temp\\DirTest\\DirTest.cmd \"%V\""
```

Please note the additional third line missing in registry output posted above.

In *Windows File Explorer* right click **on left side** on directory `C:\Windows` with currently active folder being still `C:\Windows\System32\drivers` and left click on context menu item **No working directory test** exactly as done before. The output is again as before. So there is no change for this use case.

Right click next **on right side** in *Windows File Explorer* on the directory `etc` in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers` and left click on context menu item **No working directory test**. A console window opens showing the following lines:

```
Current directory is: "C:\WINDOWS\system32"
Batch file started with: C:\Temp\DirTest\DirTest.cmd "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc"
Command line used is: "cmd.exe" /D /C C:\Temp\DirTest\DirTest.cmd "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc"
```

The first line shows the important difference with the registry string value `NoWorkingDirectory` present which is now `C:\WINDOWS\system32` instead of `C:\Windows\system32\drives` as before. The current working directory is now always the Windows system directory defined with `%SystemRoot%\system32`.

It does not matter if `NoWorkingDirectory` is added to registry without a string value or with a string value like `C:\Windows`. It can be even added a registry value of type `DWORD` with name `NoWorkingDirectory` with value `0` or `1`. The registry value type of `NoWorkingDirectory` and its value does not matter for the Windows shell (`explorer.exe`). It only matters if there is a registry value of name `NoWorkingDirectory` present or not in Windows registry under the key being used for the shell extension.

The added registry key and the batch file can be used for more analyzes like browsing to a network resource using a UNC path or right clicking on a virtual shell folder on left side in the folder tree. There can be also created in `C:\Temp\DirTest` a directory with name `Development & Test(!) 100%` and pass this folder name with full path to a batch file or executable or other script and see what happens. Many batch files fail to process correct an argument string like `"C:\Temp\DirTest\Development & Test(!) 100%"` because of spaces and exclamation mark and round brackets and a percent sign although being a valid directory name consisting only of ASCII characters.

The registry key and the batch file as well as the created directory used to demonstrate the behavior should be deleted finally by executing the following commands in the command prompt window after closing all console windows opened by running `DirTest.cmd`:

```
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\NoWorkingDirectoryTest" /f
del C:\Temp\DirTest\DirTest.cmd
rd C:\Temp\DirTest
rd C:\Temp
```

**Note:** Many of the properties of a shortcut file with file extension `.lnk` define the values passed by *Explorer* to `CreateProcess` via its function parameters and the structure `STARTUPINFO`. For example the property **Start in** defines the string value to which `lpCurrentDirectory` finally points to on making use of the shortcut file to start an executable.

**A note for programmers:**

- The C# [Process class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) is a C# wrapper class for `CreateProcess`.
- The Java [class ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is on Windows a Java wrapper class for `CreateProcess`.
- The Python [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) is on Windows a Python wrapper module for `CreateProcess`.
- The Windows Command Processor command `start` supports options which are all passed to `CreateProcess` by `cmd.exe` on using them like the option `/D` which defines the string passed to `CreateProcess` using the function parameter `lpCurrentDirectory`.

Every programming and scripting language with support for running an executable on Windows has a function or class which calls on Windows `CreateProcess` without or with a `STARTUPINFO` structure.

Answer (score 1):

The "NoWorkingDirectory" verb property is undocumented so this is just a guess:

Cmd.exe does not support remote shares (UNC) as the current directory and if you start Cmd.exe with such a working directory it will print a warning message to the console.

If you look at the "Open command window here" registration you will see that it starts Cmd.exe with the `pushd` command and `pushd` does support UNC paths. NoWorkingDirectory is just there to avoid displaying a warning message.

It is not really required for PowerShell.